ESP32: Crash during check if PubSubClient is still connected - but why?
I recently noticed some seemingly random crashs on my esp32 application.
I was able to catch a crash message which is the following and which is due to some erroneuos behaviour when I check if my PubSubClient is still connected. The MqttClient is my own wrapper around the actual PubSubClient . I created a separate task for handling the connection state which is below.

Here is my task creation :
 xTaskCreate(
        [](void *parameters)
        {
            MqttClient *mqttClient = (MqttClient *)parameters;

            while (true)
            {
                mqttClient->doConnectionCheck();
                vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            }
        },                        // Function to implement the task
        "mqttConnectionTask",     // Name of the task
        8192,                     // Stack size in words
        this,                     // Task input parameter
        1,                        // Priority of the task
        &mqttConnectionTaskHandle // Task handle
    ); 

and my actual check for the connection:
void MqttClient::doConnectionCheck()
{
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.println("Wait for WiFi");
    }
    else if (!isConnected()) // Here goes the crash
    {
        Serial.println("Try connect");
        connect(); // This function downloads certs and so on and connects the client, but that is not the crash reason. Because of the certificates I set the stack size to 8192 (?)
    }
    else
    {
        // Everything connected
    }
}

bool MqttClient::isConnected()
{
    return client->connected(); // That's the PubSubClient
}

It crashes when isConnected() is called.
Does anyone have a slight idea what is happening here?
I tried to use my PubSubClient to do some MQTT communication and in general it sometimes behaves a bit strange. For instance, it connects to my broker and cancels the connection several times in a row and then succeeds.
And obviously it crashes like described which I do not know how to solve and I have no idea why.

xTaskCreate - this may be a thread safety issue (difficult to say for sure without a MRE).
